# Virtuemart shopping cart module not showed

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, internet-explorer-8

could you please advice me how to solve this problem. I have installed joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2.0.22a on one server and when I check it on my pc on both browsers Firefox and IE11 everything is ok. But on another pc, where is IE9 there is this kind of problem:

- When I click on add to cart button no product is showed in VM Shopping Cart module
- Facebox not jump on screen (information about product adding should be showed)
- When I refresh page, everything is ok

I used IE8 developer tools and it showed me this error:

"script5007 Unable to get the property value settings: object is null or not defined"

I read that it is some problem in javascript, could you advice me, please?

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery is being imported on your site?

Comment: this is not support for every script downloadable from the internet

Comment: Apparently the VM module doesn't support IE8, you should bring this up with the developers.  Do you get the error if you put IE11 in compatibility mode and set it to IE8? IE11 has better debugging tools, you might be able to debug and trace to the source of the error.

Comment: If I used compability mode (IE9 and IE8) in IE11 I did not get this error.

Comment: And could you advice me, how I can find out what version of jQuery is imported on my site?

Comment: Is there someone who can help me, please? IE9 developer tool refer me to this row: $.facebox.settings.closeImage = closeImage; in vmprices.js file. There is some problem with value of "settings". Probably some command in js is not compatible with IE9.